# why google use http get to send the search information?

Tags: http, google-search

Looks like Google use http get to send the search information.

If I use Google to search "stackoverflow", the keyword will be attached on the url query string and send to google server.

Why Google not use Http Post, and put the "stackoverflow" into post body ??

Comment: ...and why should it?

Comment: @JulianReschke my search information will be easily leaked through Http Get

Comment: Not for HTTPS. And for HTTP, it would be leaked using POST as well.